# php: using cookies / user authentification

Tags: php, authentication

i'm looking for the optimal way for safe user authentification to my website.

i'm thinking about the following solution:

first login: asking for login data -> generating hashcode consisting of ip address, password and cookie expiration date -> storing that hashcode to database but also into a cookie.

next login: check for cookie, look for hashcode in my user database.

would that be the safest way? or will there be problems using cookies?
thanks

Comment: Are you trying to replace PHP sessions or trying to implement a "Remember me" feature?

Comment: He tries to add an authentication feature.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you will want to store a cookie in the browser that points to a record in your database somewhere that says that he is a known user.  The one thing you'll want to ensure is that that cookie id is globally unique.  So, yes, using a hash (or md5, or sha1) on a variety of unique attributes would most likely be sufficient.  Putting a `unique` on that column in your database would be a good idea as well.

Another idea would be to have a column in your users table for `cookieid`, generate that when the entry is created and ensure it's uniqueness.  Then just use that every time when that user logs in.  You could change all the values of that column for every user with a backend script every once in a while if you want to freshen up the cookies if you're really worried about security.

`will there be problems using cookies?`

Except for newer html5 features that aren't compatible with all browsers, cookies are really the only way to save login information.  Go to a big site you use, ebay, amazon, wellsfargo. Wipe all of your cookies and private data, then go there and login.  Then view your cookies.  What do they put in there?  If it's good enough for those guys, it's probably good enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way is to use php-sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"] = "foo";
$_SESSION["ip"] = "123.132.123.132";
?>
```

Comment: nice but the session will expire until next login or?

Comment: Sessions are just unique cookies that point to set of saved key/value pairs stored server side.  Sessions are dependent on cookies anyway. They also terminate at the end of the browsing session.

Comment: Sure. The credentials are saved in the database and when the user enters his username and password, a new session is generated.